# Django Dynamically Add Forms Based On Key Value Pairs List

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Is there a way to dynamically create formsets based on an API response. This would easily be done in JS, however, the app is running Django's MVT and I would like to create the form dynamically within python. Also, the API response won't come in until after the Item model is created. This form will be the second step in a flow.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ItemAspect(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

API resposne:

```
{
 [
  {
   "key": "Name",
   "value_list": [
       "value0",
        ...
    ]
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

Desired form:

```
<form>
  ...
  <label for="value-0"> {{ key }}</label>
  <select name="value-0" id="value-0">
      <option value="{{ value_list[0] }}"> {{ value_list[0] }} </option>
      ...
  </select>
  <---! The below would be handled in the view, just adding for context -->
  <input style="display: hidden;" name="name-0" value="{{ key }}">
  ...
</form>
```

My best guess is that it could be done with crispy's form_helper in a view after the API response is received.

Answer (score 1):

For those that might come across this, here is my current solution (also open to improvements):

forms.py

```py
class ItemAspectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemAspect
        exclude = ("item",)
```

views.py

```py
class ItemAspectCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = ItemAspectForm
    form_class = ItemAspectForm
    template_name = "inventory/item_aspect_form.html"
    success_message = _("Item aspect successfully created")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        item = Item.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["id"])
        aspects = [Aspect(**aspect) for aspect in get_item_aspects_for_category(item)["aspects"]]
        context = super().get_context_data()
        ItemAspectFormSet = modelformset_factory(
            model=ItemAspect,
            form=ItemAspectForm,
            can_delete=True,
            extra=len(aspects)
        )
        if self.request.POST:
            context["formset"] = ItemAspectFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context["formset"] = ItemAspectFormSet()
            for aspect, form in zip(aspects, context["formset"]):
                if aspect.has_values:
                    form.fields["value"] = forms.ChoiceField(
                        choices=((value, value) for value in aspect.values)
                    )

                form.fields["value"].required = aspect.is_required
                form.fields["value"].label = aspect.name
                form.fields["name"].initial = aspect.name
                form.fields["name"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        assert (
            self.request.user.is_authenticated
        )  # for mypy to know that the user is authenticated
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context["formset"]
        item = Item.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["id"])
        if formset.is_valid():
            aspect_forms = formset.save(commit=False)
            for aspect_form in aspect_forms:
                aspect_form.item = item
                aspect_form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


item_aspects_create = ItemAspectCreateView.as_view()
```